# Black screen comes up when I try to rotate a cube in three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I'm trying to rotate a cube about all 3 axes (x,y,z), im using the code shown below:

`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CM20219 – Coursework 2 – WebGL</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="three.js"></script>
        <script>
            "use strict"; // https://stackoverflow.com/q/1335851/72470

            // Global variables that are available in all functions.
            // Note: You can add your own here, e.g. to store the rendering mode.
            var camera, scene, renderer, mesh;

            // Initialise the scene, and draw it for the first time.
            init();
            animate();

            // Listen for keyboard events, to react to them.
            // Note: there are also other event listeners, e.g. for mouse events.
            document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
            

            // Scene initialisation. This function is only run once, at the very beginning.
            function init()
            {
                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                // Set up the camera, move it to (3, 4, 5) and look at the origin (0, 0, 0).
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
                camera.position.set(3, 4, 5);
                camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

                // Draw a helper grid in the x-z plane (note: y is up).
                scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(10, 20, 0xffffff));

                // TO DO: Draw a cube (requirement 1).

                const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
                const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
                const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                const vertices = cube.vertices 
                const wireframe = cube.wireframe
                scene.add( wireframe);
                scene.add( cube );
                scene.add( vertices );


                camera.position.z = 5;



                // TO DO: Visualise the axes of the global coordinate system (requirment 2).

                const axeshelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(5)
                scene.add(axeshelper)

                // Basic ambient lighting.
                scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff));
                // TO DO: add more complex lighting for 'face' rendering mode (requirement 4).
                
                const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
                scene.add( light );

                // Set up the Web GL renderer.
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
                renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio); // HiDPI/retina rendering
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                // Handle resizing of the browser window.
                window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize, false);
            }





            // Handle resizing of the browser window.
            function handleResize()
            {
                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            }

            // Animation loop function. This function is called whenever an update is required.
            

                


            
            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
                cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
                cube.rotation.z += 0.01;
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            }
            


            // Handle keyboard presses.
            function handleKeyDown(event)
            {
                switch (event.keyCode)
                {
                    // Render modes.
                    case 70: // f = face
                        alert('TO DO: add code for face render mode (requirement 4).');
                        break;

                    case 69: // e = edge
                        alert('TO DO: add code for edge render mode (requirement 4).');
                        break;

                    case 86: // v = vertex
                        alert('TO DO: add code for vertex render mode (requirement 4).');
                        break;

                    // TO DO: add code for starting/stopping rotations (requirement 3).
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`

I think the issue lies in the fact that I dont have access to the rotation function. Is there a way i can build this function mathematically using matrices or something? Apologies if the solution is super obvious, I'm really new to this programming language.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the `cube` variable in a scope you can access it in your animation loop. Try it with this updated code:

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, cube;

// Initialise the scene, and draw it for the first time.
init();
animate();

// Listen for keyboard events, to react to them.
// Note: there are also other event listeners, e.g. for mouse events.
document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);


// Scene initialisation. This function is only run once, at the very beginning.
function init() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // Set up the camera, move it to (3, 4, 5) and look at the origin (0, 0, 0).
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(3, 4, 5);
  camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

  // Draw a helper grid in the x-z plane (note: y is up).
  scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(10, 20, 0xffffff));

  // TO DO: Draw a cube (requirement 1).

  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x00ff00
  });
  cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(cube);

  camera.position.z = 5;

  // TO DO: Visualise the axes of the global coordinate system (requirment 2).

  const axeshelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(5)
  scene.add(axeshelper)

  // Basic ambient lighting.
  scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff));
  // TO DO: add more complex lighting for 'face' rendering mode (requirement 4).

  const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
  scene.add(light);

  // Set up the Web GL renderer.
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio); // HiDPI/retina rendering
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  // Handle resizing of the browser window.
  window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize, false);
}





// Handle resizing of the browser window.
function handleResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

// Animation loop function. This function is called whenever an update is required.






function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
  cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
  cube.rotation.z += 0.01;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}



// Handle keyboard presses.
function handleKeyDown(event) {
  switch (event.keyCode) {
    // Render modes.
    case 70: // f = face
      alert('TO DO: add code for face render mode (requirement 4).');
      break;

    case 69: // e = edge
      alert('TO DO: add code for edge render mode (requirement 4).');
      break;

    case 86: // v = vertex
      alert('TO DO: add code for vertex render mode (requirement 4).');
      break;

      // TO DO: add code for starting/stopping rotations (requirement 3).
  }
}
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.123/build/three.js"></script>
```